# How to keep closed the Sliding Menu even when user slides to open it?

Tags: android, menu, navigation-drawer, slidingdrawer

In my application, I have some screens where I don't want the drawer menu to open when the user slides. How can I do that? The app uses only one activity and the rest are fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to keep closed the Sliding Menu even when user slides to open it?

Use below method in your `Activity` and call it as your need.

```
 public void enableViews(boolean enable) {
       if (enable) {
            //You may not want to open the drawer on swipe from the left in this case
            drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
            // Remove hamburger
            toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
            // Show back button
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            // when DrawerToggle is disabled i.e. setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false), navigation icon
            // clicks are disabled i.e. the UP button will not work.
            // We need to add a listener, as in below, so DrawerToggle will forward
            // click events to this listener.
            toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Doesn't have to be onBackPressed
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            });
        } else {
            //You must regain the power of swipe for the drawer.
            drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
            // Remove back button
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

            // Show hamburger
            toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            // Remove the/any drawer toggle listener
            toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(null);
        }
    }
```

**Note:-** Call `enableViews(true)` for locking and `enableViews(false)` for unlocking

Comment: I have multiple fragments.. I can write this code in every fragment. I need something that can be written in activity

Comment: you do this in activity and call it in activity whenever you opening fragments.

Comment: @Miki Check Edit Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```